# Change text color based on switch value

Tags: php

I would like to change the color of the text value based on the value of a switch statement. For example if the value equals 'Hello' then make it green. I have included some code and would be grateful if someone could offer some assistance as to how I can achieve this. Many thanks.

```
switch ($row['destroydate']) {

  case NULL:

    $destroydate = 'No Date Set'; <---MAKE RED
    //echo $destroyeddate;
    break;

  case "0000-00-00":

    $destroydate = 'No Date Set'; <--- MAKE GREEN

    break;

  default:

    $destroydate = $row['destroydate']; <--- MAKE BLUE

    break;

}
```

Comment: I mean it depends. Do you plan to echo this output onto the page into a `<p>` tag for instance? You'll either need to add HTML around the text or insert the text into HTML tags by `echo`ing it between `<p>` and `</p>` for example.

Comment: Presumably you do know how to change the text colour in your preferred medium, presumably HTML…? What's the difficulty of putting that together with a `switch`?

Comment: The end result will be along the lines of 'activity' => $activity, which will be returned by json_encode. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 I added an answer with cleaner code. If it's easier you could mark it as the answer, if it's not, then keep it like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using

```
switch ($row['destroydate']) {

  case NULL:

    $destroydate = '<span style="color:#FF0000">No Date Set</span>'; <---MAKE RED
    //echo $destroyeddate;
    break;

  case "0000-00-00":

    $destroydate = '<span style="color:#39CD0D">No Date Set</span>'; <--- MAKE GREEN

    break;

  default:

    $destroydate = '<span style="color:#0808D8 ">'.$row["destroydate"].'</span>'; <--- MAKE BLUE

    break;

}
```

Comment: @user1532468.glade to here it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You should use this below. Create a function and use it with sending the Date data. The switch will return a result, always. This way you can always use your new function at any file. If there is anything needs to be added/changed, you don't need to change all the files who are using this switch, but only have to change the function. If you prefer: you could also make it a static function (because it's only returning some html).

```
/**
 * @param $date
 *
 * @return string
 */
    Public function getDateColor($date)
    {
        // Check on date and return result
        switch($date):
            case(empty($date)):
                return '<span color="red">No Date Set</span>';
                break;
            case($date == 0000-00-00):
                return '<span color="Green">No Date Set</span>';
                break;
            default:
                return '<span color="blue">' . $date . '</span>';
        endswitch;
    }
```